# The shortest puzzle (part 1)

Tags: riddle, word, visual

```
[![image description here][1]][1]
```

Can't you change everything? I am doing it right now.

> **Question:** What is the 1-word answer to this question?

Hint:

> R IS NEAR... (for Anonymus 25- Reinstate Monica)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> If you click the edit history of the question, you get 5 imgur links.They lead to symbols of 5 different SE sites. The sites are as following: Bicycle SE, English SE, Arqade SE, Database Administrators SE, and Roleplaying Games SE.

Some ideas of how this might apply:

> The initials of these sites are BEADR. Perhaps they can be anagrammed to BEARD/BREAD? Another idea would be WHAT, since it could be that WHAT is tindeed the 1-word answer, if we are talking about [lateral-thinking].

Those are my ideas so far. Perhaps there is something I'm missing, but I am not sure what the next step is...

Comment: I don't think the information given in this answer is too "obvious".